# SQLite: "Prepare Statement" not working

Tags: sql, sqlite, prepared-statement

I am trying to use "prepare statement" functionality from [here](http://blog.quibb.org/2010/08/fast-bulk-inserts-into-sqlite/) in C and VS2012 to save bulk data. here is my code:

```
char *sql;
char query[1000];
char buffer[100] = "INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (?NNN1, ?2, ?3)";
sqlite3_int64 i;

sprintf_s(query , "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table1("  
             "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " 
             "Name CHAR NULL , "
             "Title CHAR NULL ); ");
sql = query ;
db_execute_sql(db,sql,1);   // create the table "Table1"
fprintf(stdout,"Table1"); 

sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, buffer,strlen(buffer), &stmt,NULL);

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   sqlite3_bind_int64(stmt,1,NULL);
   sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,2,"Two",-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,3,"Three",-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

   if(sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE){
     printf("\n\nPrepare statement failed!"); // it always comes here
   }
   sqlite3_reset(stmt);
}
```

but it is not working. whenever I check the database in "SQLite administrator", I find nothing except the table itself, i.e.: No Data.

why is this happening ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C and SQLite but I see a couple things which you could try to verify: why is the identity column parameterized differently? ie "?NNN1" instead of "?1". Why is a value even provided for an autoincrement identity column and why not "INSERT INTO Table1 (Name, Title) VALUES (?1, ?2)". Last: does sqlite3_step actually execute the statement? If not, there is no need to look in the database for rows :)

Comment: You must check the return codes of *all* functions, especially `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. And when there is an error, call [sqlite3_errmsg](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

Comment: @Anton: Thanks for your reply. I put "?NNN1" in the first place as to indicate it is an Integer value (an auto-incremental primary-key). Although, when I changed it back to "?1" it works fine but I had to remove the auto-increment  primary-key, otherwise it does not work. However, I need the primary key to be auto-incremental (and that is why I used the NULL value), how can I do that with the "prepare Statement" ? .. I am guessing the prepare statement does not recognize the NULL value, right ?

Comment: @CL.: I included the generation of the error-messages now in my code .. thanks for the tip :) .. regards the return codes, they all work fine now, look at my reply to "Anton" above ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
char *sql;
char query[1000];
char buffer[100] = "INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3)";
sqlite3_int64 i;

sprintf_s(query , "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table1("  
             "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " 
             "Name CHAR NULL , "
             "Title CHAR NULL ); ");
sql = query ;
db_execute_sql(db,sql,1);   // create the table "Table1"
fprintf(stdout,"Table1"); 

sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, buffer,strlen(buffer), &stmt,NULL);

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   // remove the first insert since it is autoincremental 
   sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,2,"Two",-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,3,"Three",-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

   if(sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE){
     printf("\n\nPrepare statement failed!"); //
   }
   sqlite3_reset(stmt);
}
```